# Is a function composition Fréchet differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, frechet-derivative

I have a trouble in handling a following question.
Given a composition operator $ F :C^1([0,1]) \to C^1([0,1]) ; F(f) = f(f(x))$,  I have a Gâteaux derivative of $F$.
\begin{align}
 \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{F(f+th) - F(f) }{t} &= \frac{(f+th)(f(x)+th(x)) - f(f(x))}{t} \\
&= \frac{f(f(x)+th(x)) + th(f(x)+th(x))- f(f(x))}{t} \\
&=  \frac{f(f(x))+ tf'(f(x))h(x)+ o(t) +th(f+th(x))- f(f(x)) }{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} f'(f(x))h(x)+h(f+th(x))+\frac{o(t)}{t} \\
&= f'(f(x))h(x) + h(f(x)).
\end{align}
for given $h \in C^1([0,1])$.

Therefore, a Gâteaux derivative of $F$ at $f$ is $DF_f(h) = f'(f(x))h(x) + h(f(x))$.

Since it is a linear in terms of $h$, and continous in terms of $f$, can we say a composition operator $F$ is actually Fréchet differentiable?

I am curious that I am right.

Edit: I changed $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ to $C^1([0,1])$ with the norm $\|f\|_{C^1([0,1])} = \sup |f(x)| + \sup|f'(x)|$.

Comment: Depends entirely on the topology that you assume on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: On which topology is a function composition operator Fréchet differentiable?
I considered the topology induced by the metric $d(f,g) = \sum_k^\infty 2^{-k} \frac{ \|f-g\|_k}{1+\|f-g\|_k}$

Comment: How exactly do you define $\lVert \cdot \rVert_k$?

Comment: I define it as sup of k-th derivative $\| f \|_k = sup\{  |f^{(k)} (x) |\}$.  or I also consider the simple sup norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity respect to the main argument is not sufficient for Frechet differentiability. You can see this for the particular choice $f(x)=2x$ and $h(x)=e^\frac{1}{2-x}$:
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}[h](x) = 2e^\frac{1}{2-x}+ e^\frac{1}{2(1-x)}\implies \left\|\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}[h](x)\right\|_{\,C^1[0,1]}=+\infty.
$$
*The norm of the functional derivative depends on the functional argument $h$ in an essential way*, thus the functional derivative $\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}[h](x)$ of the functional $f\mapsto F(f)=f\big(f(x)\big)$ is not Frechet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
If I restrict $C^1([0,1])$ to a set $\{ f \in C^1([0,1]) : f(f(x)) \in C^1([0,1]) \}$, the composition operator can be Fréchet differentiable?
I think your counter-example is due to the fact that $f(x)$ is continous on $[0,1]$ but is not continous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @yeachanpark this maybe possible. However, there may be other subclasses of functions to be excluded: for example you could try to construct a rapidly $h$ oscillating function such that with a prescribed $f\in C^1[0,1]$ for which $\left\|\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}[h](x)\right\|_{\,C^1[0,1]}=\text{const.}$ as $h\to 0$. Therefore a positive answer to your question depends both on the topology you assume but also on the properties of the self-composition functional.